# Oracle time comparison returning older instead of newer times

Tags: sql, oracle, date

The end of my select query is:

```
and logoff_time > to_date('2013-11-27 14:18:42','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

yet this is returning (in SQL Developer) rows with times in `logoff_time` *before* the specified time - e.g. 3am.

Is this problem something to do with timezones? I'm in GMT and so is the server, although I don't know what timezone it thinks it is in.

This logoff_time column is [an Oracle system audit column](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_3071.htm#REFRN23021), by the way. (Actually, I've attempted to reconstruct it by a subquery directly on the underlying audit table.)

Comment: As you are comparing to static values against each other, timezones shouldn't be the problem. Can we get a little more context on your query and table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. The times were in fact newer. I was just confused by the fact that I had set them to display as `HH:MI:SS` instead of `HH24:MI:SS` in the SQL Developer preferences, so I was looking at 03 and thinking that meant 3am instead of 3pm.